# Unity iOS unintentionally storing Documents & data

Tags: ios, mobile, unity-game-engine

I have a rather basic game that runs on iOS. The only persistent data I store is an integer representing the high score, however upon running the app, I noticed it stores around 6 MB of data.

Does anyone know what exactly it stores in those 6 MB of data?

Comment: Is this with the `PlayerPrefs` class?

Comment: Yes; PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", playerStats.GetStat(StatType.Score));

Comment: It will take reverse-engineering your app to see what unity is actually doing. I believe they are creating a binary file and writing other stuff is it too.